# SQL selecting record with only uniqe value

Tags: sql

I have two columns, one is "Name" and second is "Number".
I have to select record where "Number" is 4. But tricky part is that in every single "Name" "Number" should have 4. For example:

Adam occurs two times one with number 4 and one with number 5 and Adam shouldn't be return.
But if another name is two times and two times have value 4 it should be return.

How to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having min(number) = max(number) and min(number) = 4;
```